# Hibernate status

Tags: hibernate, web, jboss

Does anyone know what's going on with Hibernate?  For a few days hibernate.org was redirecting to "jboss.org," but for the past 2-3 days it's just showing a jboss.org maintenance screen.

I realize Hibernate has always been associated with JBoss, so I'm not asking about that, but I use Hibernate in multiple projects, and I use the online documentation quite a bit, so I'm wondering where/when this site will reappear.  (I'm not asking about NHibernate, just plain-old Java Hibernate).

I would ask this on the hibernate forum or the jboss forum, but these are both unavailable at the moment.  (Also, the link to hibernate on jboss.org is "hibernate.org" which is useless).  Just curious if anyone in this community knows anything.

Here are related questons that didn't really get sufficient answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761425/whats-happening-to-hibernate-org-closed

Comment: as of 5 May hibernate.org seems to be back up and operational

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably the JBoss.org team know (it says so right there on hibernate.org). Their web site has a [contact us](http://jboss.org/contact.html) link which I'm sure would be more likely to get an intelligent response from them than the SO swarm :-). No offense intended.

For what it's worth, I asked them. Let's see what they come back with.

Comment: Fair enough :)  I'll send them an email, and see what happens.  If I get a response, I'll post it up here for all to see!

Answer (score 1):

I emailed them on Friday before the maintenance message was even up, and posted messages on the JBoss forum to no avail. I'd be surprised if they responded, otherwise I'd expect they'd have put up a message indicating the nature of the problem and the expected return time. A pretty shabby way of doing business if you ask me.

If you go to the Internet Archive (just google 'wayback machine') and search on hibernate.org you can pull up snapshots of the site including most of the documentation. Not the most recent docs, but still better than nothing.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, seems pretty shady.  Thanks a lot for your response, I have little faith that I'm going to get a response back, since they're not even bothering to update their maintenance screen or provide any information.